# 'Cannot access a disposed object' error while saving object

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a problem while saving object to db using linq2sql

Here is the code:

```
static DataContext dataContext = new DataContext();    
public static void ConfirmationPaymentOrder(ConfirmPayments data)
    {
        using (dataContext = new DataContext(DBConnection))
        {
            foreach (OrdersConfirm orderConfirm in data.OrdersConfirm)
            {
                var result = SendRequestToConfirm(orderConfirm.Orders, orderConfirm.UserName, orderConfirm.Password);

                dataContext.Orders.InsertOnSubmit(orderConfirm);

                dataContext.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'DataContext accessed after Dispose.'.
```

How do I solve the issue?

Comment: Your datacontext is apparently a static field, not a local variable. Are you disposing it in a another method?

Comment: You got this error  after call  dataContext.SubmitChanges()?

Comment: @JonasH I added line where my datacontext declared. Are you disposing it in a another method? - No

Comment: Is the code running in a multithreaded context, e.g. a web app?

Comment: @JonasH Yes it is a wcf application

Comment: Then you should not use static unless you're sure wcf is configured to only let one thread access the code at a time.

Comment: @M.Azad according to call stack I got the error on the blank line between dataContext.Orders.InsertOnSubmit(orderConfirm); and dataContext.SubmitChanges();

Comment: @JonasH I should not use static datacontext or static method?

Comment: Avoid static fields (and auto-properties)

Comment: Remove the static `dataContext` field, change the code to `using (var dataContext = ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not share a connection object (static), this will lead to this kind of problems. A static object should only be created ones. Move the declaration inside the method.

```
public static void ConfirmationPaymentOrder(ConfirmPayments data)
{
    using (var dataContext = new DataContext(DBConnection))
    {
        foreach (OrdersConfirm orderConfirm in data.OrdersConfirm)
        {
            var result = SendRequestToConfirm(orderConfirm.Orders, orderConfirm.UserName, orderConfirm.Password);

            dataContext.Orders.InsertOnSubmit(orderConfirm);
        }
        dataContext.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

---

Good job for noticing the SubmitChanges inside the loop: C. Knight

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth moving the dataContext.SubmitChanges() outside the foreach loop.  Don't know whether this will fix the issue but might be worth a try as there doesn't seem to be any reason (in your example) to call SubmitChanges() multiple times.

Also I presume you haven't disposed of the DBConnection object previously by accident?